# C++11: Variadic template deduction logic

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I have the following construct:

```
template <class... Args>
class some_class
{
public:
    some_class() = default;
    some_class(Args...) = delete;
    ~some_class() = default;
};

template<>
class some_class<void>
{
public:
    some_class() = default;
    ~some_class() = default;
};
```

The reason for this is that I just want to allow the users to create objects using the default constructor, so for example:

```
some_class<int,float> b;
```

should work but

```
some_class<int,float> c(1,3.4);
```

should give me a compilation error.

At some point in time I also needed to create templates based on `void` hence, the specialization for `void`:

```
some_class<void> a;
```

But by mistake I have typed:

```
some_class<> d;
```

And suddenly my code stopped compiling and it gave me the error:

```
some_class<Args>::some_class(Args ...) [with Args = {}]’ cannot be 
overloaded
 some_class(Args...) = delete;
```

So here comes the question: I feel that I am wrong that I assume that `some_class<>` should be deduced to the `void` specialization... I just don't know why. Can please someone explain why `some_class<>` (ie: empty argument list) is different from `some_class<void>`? (A few lines from the standard will do :) )

https://ideone.com/o6u0D6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void` is a type like any other (an incomplete type, to be precise). This means it can be used as a template argument for type template parameters normally. Taking your class template, these are all perfectly valid, and *distinct,* instantiations:

```
some_class<void>
some_class<void, void>
some_class<void, void, void>
some_class<void, char, void>
```

In the first case, the parameter pack `Args` has one element: `void`. In the second case, it has two elements: `void` and `void`. And so on.

This is quite different from the case `some_class<>`, in which case the parameter pack has *zero* elements. You can easily demonstrate this using `sizeof...`:

```
template <class... Pack>
struct Sizer
{
  static constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(Pack);
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << Sizer<>::size << ' ' << Sizer<void>::size << ' ' << Sizer<void, void>::size << std::endl;
}
```

This will output:

> 0 1 2

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/704c7d5884d2e90a)

I can't really think of a relevant part of the standard to quote. Perhaps this (C++11 [temp.variadic] 14.5.3/1):

> A *template parameter pack* is a template parameter that accepts zero or more template arguments. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class ... Types> struct Tuple { };
> Tuple<> t0; // Types contains no arguments
> Tuple<int> t1; // Types contains one argument: int
> Tuple<int, float> t2; // Types contains two arguments: int and float
> Tuple<0> error; // error: 0 is not a type
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

Comment: Thanks, your answer perfectly explains the situation... My original problem is a bit above this level, since I use the parameter pack as argument types to some functions in the class (so I automatically translated `void` to something which takes no arguments) and I even have the situation when specific values are instantiated from the argument pack, so due to this restraint it actually never occurred to me to put there `<void,void>` but indeed this answer describes the situation clearly.